# One to many relationship on viewModels of Knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js, relationship, viewmodel, one-to-many

I am newbie on KO. I try to design a simple application with knockout.js, but I couldn't figure out how to design modelViews and models.

I try to load tasks when the a feature row clicked. But after once load, then I want to show it from memory, not from database. For example when all features clicked, then there will be no database query on current session.

On KO, I don't know where to put my observableArrays (tasks,notes).

Should they be a property of models or viewModels?

Here my application structure.
Feature(s) has many tasks, task(s) has many note.
[image: Feature, task,note]

UI is like...
[image]

ViewModels:

```
var taskViewModel = {
     notes: ko.observableArray(),

     addNote: function (newNote) {
         this.notes.push(newNote);
  }
} 

var featureViewModel = {
    tasks: ko.observableArray(),

    addTask: function(newTask){
             this.tasks.push(newTask);
},

taskClicked: function (selectedTask) {
        GetNotes(selectedTask.TaskId);
         }
}

var projectViewModel = new projectViewModelFunc();
function projectViewModelFunc() {
    var self = this;
    self.features = ko.observableArray();

    self.addFeature = function (newFeature) {
         this.features.push(newFeature);
       };
}

ko.applyBindings(taskViewModel, $('#notes')[0]);
ko.applyBindings(featureViewModel, $('#tasksPanel')[0]);
ko.applyBindings(projectViewModel, $('#features')[0]);
```

Models:

```
function noteModel(data) {
   this.UserCreatedFullName= data.UserCreated.FullName;
   this.CreatedDate = data.CreatedDate;
   this.NoteId = data.NoteId;
   this.Content = data.Content;
   this.TaskId = data.TaskId;

   this.TaskHeader = function () { return this.UserCreatedFullName + " (" + this.CreatedDate + ") : "; };
}

function taskModel(data) {
    this.TaskId = data.TaskId;
    this.Title = data.Name;
    this.Status = data.Status.Name;
    this.CreatedDate = data.CreatedDate;
    this.UserCreatedFullName = data.UserCreated.FullName;
}

function featureModel(data, selected) {
    var self = this;
    self.FeatureId = data.FeatureId;
    self.Name = data.Name;
    self.Status = data.Status.Name;
    self.CreatedDate = data.CreatedDate;
    self.UserCreatedFullName = data.UserCreated.FullName;

    this.IsSelected = ko.computed(function () {
        return selected() === self;
    });
}
```

DB context functions(just for more clearance)

```
function GetNotes(taskId) {
    var url = "/Note/GetNotes";
    taskViewModel.resetNotes();
    $.get(url, { "TaskId": taskId }, function (data) {
        $.each(JSON.parse(data), function (i, item) {
            taskViewModel.addNote(new noteModel(item));
        });
    });
};

function GetFeatures() {
    var url = "/Project/GetFeatures";
    taskViewModel.resetNotes();
    $.get(url, "", function (data) {
        $.each(JSON.parse(data), function (i, item) {
            projectViewModel.addFeature(new featureModel(item, projectViewModel.selectedFeature));
        });
    });
};

function GetTasks(FeatureId) {
    var url = "/Task/GetTaskList";
    $.get(url, { "FeatureId": FeatureId }, function (data) {

        $.each(JSON.parse(data), function (i, item) {
            featureViewModel.addTask(new taskModel(item));
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start looking here
http://knockoutjs.com/examples/collections.html

And this one would be similar too.
[Knockoutjs nested observableArrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25784715/knockoutjs-nested-observablearrays)